# d3 - select/unselect node onclick

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rwd4q/) the select logic works but the unselect logic does not.
I have no idea why.

```
var selected;
function click(){

  // If nothing is selected then select the clicked node.
  if(!selected){
    selected = d3.select(this);
    selected.style('stroke', 'black');
  }

  // If the clicked node is already selected then unselect it.
  else if(selected == d3.select(this)){
    selected.style('stroke', 'white');
    selected = undefined;
  }
}
```

Comment: A simple else should suffice, you don't need the additional check.

Comment: Not true because I want the user to have to click a selected node to unselect it. Also, it doesn't answer the question of why the else if logic is not working as expected.

Comment: The comparison fails because you're comparing the references to two array-ish objects (the selection) which, as you're constructing them separately, are not the same. It works if you compare the objects inside the selection: http://jsfiddle.net/Rwd4q/5/

Comment: `if(selected.node() === this)` is what you need...

Answer (score 1):

Once you changed the style, the object selected is not the previous d3 object. Either change the style before assigning to the variable or use the html element instead. Hope this will work.

```
var selected;
function click(){       
   if(!selected){
     selected = this;
     d3.select(selected).style('stroke', 'black');
  } 
  else if(selected == this){
     d3.select(selected).style('stroke', 'white');
     selected = undefined;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep track of the node selected, as opposed to using a **global** `selected` variable. Here:

```
//var selected; // get rid of this
if (!d3.select(this).classed("selected")) {
   d3.select(this)
       .style('stroke', 'black')
       .classed("selected",true)
} 
else {
  d3.select(this)
      .style('stroke', 'white')
      .classed("selected",false);
}
```

Here is an [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/Rwd4q/4/) of your fiddle.

Comment: Okay this is an alternative approach (except I only want to allow a single node to be selected at any time) however I still don't understand why my original approach doesn't work. Is it not valid javascript or logic?

Comment: @CathalCoffey Ok, the single node selection constraint was not specified in the question, so I did not know.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer because of comment restrictions.

Similar to what @Gilsha answered, if you replace the `selected = undefined` with what occurs during `if(!selected){...}` the user can select a node seamlessly.

With @Gilsha's answer the user can select a node but if they want to select another node while something is already selected it will just deselect the other node.

```
var selected;
function click(){       
  if(!selected){
     selected = this;
     d3.select(selected).style('stroke', 'black');
  } 
  else if(selected == this){
     d3.select(selected).style('stroke', 'white');
     selected = this;
     d3.select(selected).style('stroke', 'black');
  } 
}
```

With the above code a user can select a node regardless of whether a node is currently selected and it will automatically deselect a node.

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rwd4q/14/